# Calling hook after data isn't null?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I an trying to use a custom hook, but need to make sure I have fetched some data before I can call it. Since I can't use conditions to call it, I am using a condition that will make that call of the hook fail instead. Is there a better way of doing this? I need to wait until user is no longer null before calling useDocument().

```
function App() {
  const { user, authIsReady } = useAuthContext();
  // // get the document with useDocument
  const { error, document: userData } = useDocument(
    "users",
    user ? user.uid : "1"
  );
  return (
    <div>App</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: what does `useDocument` do? Can you add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please. This is not sufficient code. Although you can pass `null` to `useDocument`, and You can do something based on the value passed. like if it is null don't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do 2 things.

1. write `useDocument` hook that way it can work with null user
2. render a component in your `<App />` and use `useDocument` hook in this component:

```
const AppComponent = ({ user }) => {
  // get the document with useDocument
  const { error, document: userData } = useDocument(
    "users",
    user.uid
  )

  return "something"
}


function App() {
  const { user, authIsReady } = useAuthContext();
  
  if (!user) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <AppComponent user={user} />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks yeah was wondering if there was some sort of trick, but changing the useDocument works for me.